# Drools - How can I import the java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit in a Guided Decision Table, using the GUI

Tags: drools, redhat

Using the Red Hat Decision Manager Workbench GUI, is there a way to import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit; into my Guided Decision Table so I can modify a fact like this...

```
    modify( $record) {
            setDAYS_AGO_RCVD((int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between($record.START_DATE, $record.END_DATE))
    }
```

If I implement this using a Java app the raw DRL looks something like this ...

```
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

rule "Set Days Ago"
    when
        $record : FactObject ( );
    then
        modify( $record ) {
                setDAYS_AGO((int) ChronoUnit.DAYS.between($record.Start_Date, $record.End_Date))
        }   
end
```

How do I get the import to appear in the DRL code created Guided Decision Table user interface or wizard?

Answer (score 0):

Found it...

Navigate to the Project Overview panel.

1. Select any object.
2. Click the ">" icon towards the upper left.
3. Click the Settings "gear" and make sure your in Repository View
   mode.
4. Click the "projects.import" file in the repository panel on the
   left.

You should now be at an "External Imports" screen.

1. Click the "New Item" button.
2. Enter the package name to import, in my case it was -
   java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit
3. Click "Ok" to update the project

The imported package should now be available in your project.

Note: You should "Build" your project to ensure it still compiles correctly and that the newly imported package will be avaiable.